# Is recursion preferred compare to iteration in multicore era?

Tags: recursion, iteration, cpu, multicore

Or say, do multicore CPUs process recursion faster than iteration?

Or it simply depends on how one language runs on the machine?
like c executes function calls with large cost, comparing to doing simple iterations.

I had this question because one day I told one of my friend that recursion isn't any amazing magic that can speed up programs, and he told me that with multicore CPUs recursion can be faster than iteration.

#### EDIT:

If we consider the most recursion-loved situation (data structure, function call),
**is it even possible for recursion to be faster?**

#### EDIT ont Oct 12th:

So how are the multicore cpus performing for now?
Are the softwares nowadays all programed for multi-core cpus?

Comment: For one: Recursive divide-and-conquer algorithms are a lot easier to parallelize than iterative ones with fine-grained dependencies.

Comment: recursive loops cannot be vectorized but on the other hand iterative loop can be vectorized with some restrictions.

Comment: @Mysticial so it can be the case that recursion runs faster than iteration?

Comment: You're mixing up different concepts here. A multi-core computer won't magically take a recursive algorithm and parallelize it for you. You have to do it yourself. So if you had a side-by-side comparison of a recursive vs. iterative algorithm, you will not get the benefit of multiple cores unless you actually parallelize the recursive implementation.

Comment: @Mysticial thank you for pointing it out, does it mean that before we explicitly writing parallelized code, our code only runs on one core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are really two ways to look at this problem:

**1.** Looking purely at the compiled code, then yes, iteration is faster than recursion. This is because recursion adds a function call (=overhead), and iteration does not. However, a common type of recursion is tail recursion: the recursive call is made at the end of the function. This is always [optimized to iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion_optimization) by compilers. So in that case it does not matter. Ergo: in some cases recursion is slower, but it is never faster.

**2.** From a functional programming viewpoint, most of the time recursive functions are written to be without [side effects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). (Having side effects in a recursive function would make it really difficult to get it to produce correct results.) If a function doesn't have side effects, then it is trivial to parallelize (thus easier to run on a multicore system). This isn't a property of recursive functions per se, but that could be the reason why your friend argues that recursion can be faster than iteration.

Answer (score 1):

While the recursion is elegant and mathematically beautiful, it consumes a lot of resources, especially memory. If you have an efficient iterative solution, You should go for that.